# Add to a cursor object prototype in meteor server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to modify a cursor like so.

```
Players.find({
  'characters.realm': realm
}).populate();
```

On the client, I am able to do it like so.

```
Mongo.Cursor.prototype.populate = function () { /** function here */ }
```

However, the same does not work on the server, and I can't find the type of `[Mongo.Collection].find()`. I've tried the following:

```
> Players.find() instanceof Mongo.Cursor
false
> Players.find().constructor.name
''
> Object.prototype.toString.call(Players.find());
'[object Object]'
```

Is there any way to add to the prototype of a selector in meteor server?

Comment: Check out collection-helpers. Perfect package for the job. https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/collection-helpers

Comment: Ah okay, that does help actually, can copy what he did.